# When I use @walletconnect/web3 provider in Vue, the following error occurs on the browser console

Tags: vue.js, web3js

This is the TS code:

```
import WalletConnectProvider from "@walletconnect/web3-provider";

export const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
  infuraId: "e4ea80f8c3764a1ea0a582a4846d708c"
});
```

The browser console reports the following error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that share code as images instead of code blocks usually indicate you haven't read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and people often skip right over them. So share your code as indicated. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: There's not much information in this question but there could be many reasons for that error. 1. There's an error in the package. 2. The package might not be functional in the environment you've chosen. 3. You are potentially using it incorrectly as it's not exactly like the packages example usage. Not much more to say other than what's already been commented

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        assert: false,
        stream: false,
        os: false,
        url: false,
        http: false,
        https: false,
        buffer: require.resolve('buffer')
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser',
        Buffer: [ 'buffer', 'Buffer' ]
      })
    ],
  } 
};
```